# how to deploy website in IIS with a host name

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I try to host my application in IIS 
below are the steps that is followed

publish the code and place it in a path.

Open IIS right click on "sites" and select "Add Website".

In that i gave The site name and selected The app pool created for the application.

I selected the physical path of the published code.

I left the Ip and port in under binding section unaltered.

and gave host name as FUS.KM.com .

When i try to browse the application the page is not Loading
"Internet explore cannot display the Page"

The machine domain is KM.com

please help me resolving the issue

Comment: Is there a DNS entry for `FUS.KM.com` that would point to the IP of the machine the site is running on?

Comment: i Made entry in the host file for the host name with the IP. Is that what u r mentioning??

Comment: That's one option, if you made the entry in the host file on the machine IIS is running on, the IP it should refer to is `127.0.0.1`. After making that addition and saving the file, you should run `ipconfig /flushdns` at the command prompt and attempt to view the site at `http://fus.km.com` in IE on the machine the host file has been edited on.

Comment: i tried flushing DNS and tried to browse the url It asked for user credentials (FYI I use windows authentication). I gave my creds And it didnt login. It is not logging in for any user creds. if i host he same within default website it works fine.

Comment: I get the error "HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."